# Models of the successor function

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, axioms

I would like to ask a few questions about models of the succesor function (s(x)=x+1), intact that is a bit vague, consider $T_{S}$ to be the set of axioms given by;

S1: $\forall xy[s(x)=s(y) \rightarrow x=y]$ (injective)

S2: $[s(x) \neq 0]$ (never $0$)

S3: $\forall x[x \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists y[s(y)=x]]$ (everything bar $0$ is in image)

S$4_{n}$ : $\forall x[s^{n}(x)\neq x]$ (no cycles)

clearly $\langle \mathbb{N};s,0 \rangle$ is a model of $T_{S}$ and the upward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem theorem tells us there are models of $T_{S}$ of every infinite cardinality furthermore i have shown every model has a substructure isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ and then for a model M not equal to $\mathbb{N}$ each element that is not a natural number creates a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$

I proved this by saying that if a isn't an element of $\mathbb{N}$ (we are using this loosely here to talk about the substructure isomorphic to the naturals.) then it can't be one of the elements of $s^{k}(a_{0})$ so there has to be an element b such that $s(b)=a$ which also can't be any of the powers of the successor function, we do the same for b, etc and so we get a set of distinct elements isomorphic to the integers.

This is as far as i have gotten with my study of the successor function, what remains for me to show is the following,

1)Make the above more rigorous by showing that any model $M$ of $T_{s}$ is isomorphic to a model $M_{I}$ with domain $\mathbb{N} \cup (I \times \mathbb{Z})$ such that each $(i,n) \in  (I \times \mathbb{Z})$ satisfies $S^{M_{I}}((i,n))=(i,n+1)$

2)Show that $M_{I_{1}} \cong M_{I_{2}}$ if and only if $I_{1}$ has the same cardinality as $I_{2}$

3)Show that the cardinality of $M_{I}$ is $ |I| + \aleph_{0}$

From all the above we know that $T_{S}$  is categorical in all uncountable cardinalities and it has no finite models so it is a complete theory (los caught) so our list of axioms is complete. Awesome!

I need help proving 1-3 any hints or model proofs would be greatly appreciated,

once that is done i need to answer one final thing

4)How many countable models are there up to isomorphism for $T_{S}$

Comment: Forget for a while about the initial $\mathbb{N}$ part. If $x$ and $y$ belong to the rest, put $x\equiv y$ if one can be reached from the other by successor. Pick an element $0_i$ in each equivalence class. That will give you the required isomorphism.

Comment: Contrary to what *Dan* says, there is no first-order version of the induction axiom. Instead there is a first-order axiom schema. Also, he doesn't really know logic and that is why his post does not answer your question at all.

Comment: It's also called "Łoś–Vaught test". *André*'s comment is the correct way to go. The main point is that since each chain is countably infinite, given any model of some uncountable cardinality $k$ the number of chains is also $k$ by cartesian product. This argument fails in the case when the model is countable, in which you should be able to see what are the possible number of chains, answering (4).

Answer (score 2):

These axioms won't adequately describe the natural numbers. First, you should start with $s:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ or some equivalent.

Your axioms will not rule out a structure consisting of two main sequences -- one that looks like the regular set of natural numbers going off to infinity in one direction starting from $0$, the other like the integers going off to infinity in both directions.

$$ 0\to 1 \to 2\to 3 \to 4 \to\cdots$$

$$+$$

$$\cdots\to (-2)\to (-1) \to (+0) \to (+1) \to (+2)\to\cdots$$

Notice that there would be no cycles or loops here.

Your final axiom should be more like:

$$\forall P\subset \mathbb{N}: [0\in P \land \forall x\in P:[s(x)\in P] \implies P=\mathbb{N}]$$

This will rule out the above structure leaving you with only:

$$ 0\to 1 \to 2\to 3 \to 4 \to\cdots$$

Comment: The axiom you have given however is not of first order, and we have been told to use first order axioms only within our study of the successor function for the course we are taking,

Comment: There may be a first-order version of the induction axiom that accomplishes the same thing -- not sure